# Restkit nested object mapping weird issue

Tags: dynamic, nested, mapping, restkit-0.26.x

I'm trying to map the following JSON response with **Restkit**:

```
{
  "container": {
    "id": 1,
    "infos": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "...",
        "type": 6,
        "value": {
          "d0": {
            "periods": [ 
              { "close": "12.30", "open": "09.00" },
              { "close": "19.30", "open": "15.30" }
             ]
          },
          "d1": {...},
          "d2": {...},
          "d3": {...},
          "d4": {...},
          "d5": {...},
          "d6": {...}
        },
        "created": "2015-12-08T17:18:05.732Z",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where the structure inside `"value"` is dynamic - that is can vary according to the type of response returned by the API. The object classes implemented are as follows:

```m
@interface CFFContainer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *infos;
@end

@interface CFFInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *value;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *created;
@end

@interface CFFOpeningTimes : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d0;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CFFOpeningDay *d6;
@end

@interface CFFOpeningDay : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *periods;
@end

@interface CFFPeriod : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *open;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *close;
@end
```

(not sure if I can use a generic **NSMutableDictionary** for `CFFInfo.value`, but I cannot assign a specific type, since I do not know what the actual structure of the entity will be).
And finally the mappings:

```m
// Container.
[containerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"identifier": @"id"}];
RKRelationshipMapping *infoMapping = 
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"infos"
                                            toKeyPath:@"infos"
                                          withMapping:[CFFInfo mapping]];
[responseMapping addPropertyMapping:infoMapping];

// Info.
[infoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"identifier": @"id", @"name": @"name", @"type": @"type", @"created": @"created"}];

// Create dynamic mapping for surveys, opening times, news, etc.    
RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [[RKDynamicMapping alloc] init];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    if ([[representation valueForKey:@"name"] containsString:@"Survey"]) {
        return [CFFSurvey mapping];
    } else if ([representation valueForKey:@"d0"] != nil) {
        return [CFFOpeningTimes mapping];
    } else if ([[representation valueForKey:@"name"] containsString:@"News"]) {
        return [CFFNews mapping];
    }
    return nil;
}];

RKRelationshipMapping *valueMapping =
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"value"
                                            toKeyPath:@"value"
                                          withMapping:dynamicMapping];
[infoMapping addPropertyMapping: valueMapping];

// Opening times.
RKRelationshipMapping * d0mapping =
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"d0"
                                            toKeyPath:@"d0"
                                          withMapping:[CFFOpeningDay mapping]];
[openingTimesMapping addPropertyMapping:d0mapping];
// ... same for d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6...

// Opening day.
RKRelationshipMapping *periodsMapping =
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"periods"
                                            toKeyPath:@"periods"
                                          withMapping:[CFFPeriod mapping]];
[periodMapping addPropertyMapping:periodsMapping];

// Period.
[periodMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"open": @"open", @"close": @"close"}];
```

All the mapping operations run smoothly, but although the logs show the matches for all the entities, in the end I get a `container.infos[0].value` object with 0 key/value pairs. The logs actually says:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:887
Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'value' to 'value'.
Value: <CFFOpeningTimes: 0x796eb6d0>
```

The weird thing is that if a different dynamic mapping is applied for `value` (such as `[CFFSurvey mapping]`) the mapped object contains the correct data. I also tried to debug the execution of the mapping operations, and as far as I could see, the `mapNestedObject:toObject:parent:withRelationshipMapping:metadataList:` method in *RKMappingOperation.m* - line 883 seems not to copy the mapped nested object to the destination object returned.

I'm really going mad about this. Any ideas about where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what the problem was. As I pointed out, the `NSMutableDictionary`type for `CFFInfo.value` is clearly not compliant with the generic structures that may be mapped onto it.

So I just substituted that type with a more generic `NSObject<NSCopying>`.

```m
@interface CFFInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject<NSCopying> *value;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *created;
@end
```

I added the `NSCopying` protocol and implemented the `copyWithZone:` method for the `CFFOpeningTimes` class and the classes used in cascade, to assure all the data is copied correctly, in case a copy of that object is needed.